# Parsing words from string in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to extract the words from a string in C and I'm getting unexpected results. I have print statements that seem to confirm my control flow, but printing the final array returns nothing.

In the code below I'm parsing trying to parse `input`, which is the string `"Some stuff  \t to parse &"`. I want to turn that string into `params[0] = "Some"; params[1] = "stuff"; params[2] = "to"; params[3] = "parse"; params[4] = "&";`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_PARAMS 10
#define MAX_WORDS 100

void parse(void);
char* input = "Some stuff  \t to parse &";
char* params[MAX_PARAMS+1] = {NULL};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    parse();
    // Prints nothing!
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_PARAMS; i++) {
        puts(params[i]);
    }
}

void parse(void) {
    char buffer[MAX_WORDS];
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_WORDS);
    int param = 0;
    int buff = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if (isspace(input[i]) && *buffer) {
            printf("Buffer '%s' being added to params[%d]\n", buffer, param);
            params[param++] = buffer;
            memset(buffer, 0, MAX_WORDS);
            buff = 0;
            if (param == MAX_PARAMS) {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (!isspace(input[i])) {
            buffer[buff++] = input[i];
            printf("%c added to buffer\n", input[i]);
        }
    }

    if (param < MAX_PARAMS && strcmp(buffer, "")) {
        params[param] = buffer;
        printf("Buffer '%s' being added to params[%d]\n", buffer, param);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems easier to use `strtok`(apply copy).

Comment: `params[param++] = buffer;` : you set local address.

Comment: Each time you save a word with `params[param++] = buffer;`, the next thing you do is zero out the the buffer with `memset(buffer, 0, MAX_WORDS);` so all the saved values are pointing to the same memory, and you keep zapping the memory the words point at to all bytes null.  (It's also a local variable, as others have pointed out.)  You need to make a copy of the buffer — use `strdup()`, implementing it if necessary (it isn't hard to implement).

Comment: Ahh now I see, creating a duplicate of the buffer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is at least one mistake in your code: your `params` array of pointers actually point to local variables `buffer` whose scope ends within `parse()` - that causes undefined behavior.

I'd be surprised if for this purpose you can't utilize standard function `strtok`

It is as simple as:

```
char input[] = "Some stuff  \t to parse &";  // <- you need to change to array because `strtok` change the string in place

char * pch = strtok (input," \t");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " \t");
}
```

---

Functional code:

```
void parse(void);
char input[] = "Some stuff  \t to parse &";
char* params[MAX_PARAMS+1] = {NULL};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    parse();
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_PARAMS && params[i]; i++) {
        puts(params[i]);
    }
}

void parse(void) {
    int i = 0;
    char * pch = strtok (input," \t");
    params[i++] = pch;
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        pch = strtok (NULL, " \t");
        params[i++] = pch;
    }        
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm doing it character by character is that there is more functionality to be added in to the parsing (there are certain special characters I'm expecting that I want to treat differently).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a copy of the buffer you are storing, otherwise you will overwrite the addresses of the buffers you are parsing.

You can do two things to solve this:

1. Use [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm), to set aside enough memory from the buffer to copy into your array.
2. Use [`strdup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) which returns a pointer to a null terminated string, which pretty much duplicates the string you are trying to copy, using [`strcpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) off course.

With either of these methods, you must [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) them in order to prevent memory leak or other bad things.

In this example I used `malloc()`, but it can also be easily done with `strdup()` too.

Note: This is a character by character brute force approach. As others have said, using `strtok()` would make life easier, however, if you are looking for the first approach, something like this would be what you want.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_PARAMS 10
#define MAX_WORDS 100

void parse(char *input, char *params[]);
void add_param(char *params[], char buffer[], int *currparam);
void print_and_free_params(char *params[], int n);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char input[] = "Some stuff to parse &";
    char *params[MAX_PARAMS+1] = {NULL};

    parse(input, params);

    return 0;
}

void
parse(char *input, char *params[]) {
    int i, param = 0, buff_count = 0;
    char buffer[MAX_WORDS];

    for (i = 0; input[i] && param < MAX_PARAMS; i++) {
        if ((isspace(input[i]) && *buffer)) {
            add_param(params, buffer, &param);
            buff_count = 0;

        } else if (!isspace(input[i])) {
            buffer[buff_count++] = input[i];
            buffer[buff_count] = '\0';
        }

        if (i == strlen(input)-1 && *buffer) {
            add_param(params, buffer, &param);
            buff_count = 0;
        }
    }

    print_and_free_params(params, param);
}

void
add_param(char *params[], char buffer[], int *currparam) {
    params[*currparam] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
    if (params[*currparam] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error mallocing space for string");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(params[*currparam], buffer);

    (*currparam)++;
}

void
print_and_free_params(char *params[], int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("params[%d] = %s\n", i, params[i]);
        free(params[i]);
        params[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Program output here: [Demo](http://ideone.com/eq7VMz)